# Excel VBA: Input Box Text and lists

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that does not work:

```
Dim ReturnType As String
ReturnType = UCase(Application.InputBox("Enter Return Type (ABC, BCD, CDE):  ", "Input Box Text", Type:=2))

If Not IsError(Application.Match(Left(ReturnType, 1), Array("ABC", "BCD", "CDE"), 0)) Then
    If CBool(InStr(1, ReturnType, "ABC", vbTextCompare)) Then
        Range("A1") = "ABC"
    End If
    If CBool(InStr(1, ReturnType, "BCD", vbTextCompare)) Then
        Range("A2") = "BCD"
    End If
    If CBool(InStr(1, ReturnType, "CDE", vbTextCompare)) Then
        Range("A3") = "CDE"
    End If
End If
```

However, if I simply change the inputs to "A", "B", and "C", it works. I think it has to do with overlapping letters. Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: you are only grabbing the first letter here: `Left(ReturnType, 1)`  change the `1` to `3`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you, this worked!